# PHP: Unique visits/hits to specific items using cookies/ip

Tags: php, cookies, count

I use a simple MySQL table to count day hits for specific pages/items in a website. Using 'id' column for page/item ids, 'date' for the day of the visits/hits, and 'hits' column for the number of hits.

Everytime someone visit the page the value of hits for that specific date is updated to +1.

But, the value is updated one more time each time the page is refreshed or revisited and I need a way to save the page ID in a cookie or the visitor IP in the database to update the hits just one time.

I never worked with cookies so I dont really know how to do it and the limitations of the data than can be stored in a cookie.

I think saving the IP adresses of the visitors in the database is a really waste of queires and bandwitch and I read that its not always possible to get the real IP and this can make some problems and some hits not updated.

I also read that its better not to use GLOBAL variables too much...

Can someone please explain me the best way to do it and how to do it??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd rather deal with cookies as PHP variables, something you are very familiar with most likely, I'd use a session.

```
session_start()
$page = 1; // Page ID
if(isset($_SESSION[$page]))
{
    // Do something if the person refreshed
}
else
{
     $_SESSION[$page] = time();
     // record hit.
}
```

Get the Page ID in the $page variable, and it will save it in a session. A session is like a cookie, except it is saved on the server side.

Basically, if there is a variable with the ID of that page, it will do nothing, else it records a hit and sets the variable.

You can check this tutorial for more on sessions: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Like cookies, Sessions will only last for a certain amount of time. So it will record a visit after a few days.

You might even want to , manually check to see when the last time visited was. If it is over an hour, record a new hit, because they probably aren't just refreshing.