# Unreliable reading of $_SESSION data

Tags: php, session

I have two PHP files that I have abstracted below:
FILE 1: login.php

```
<?
ob_start();
session_start();
$q = "SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_priv, user_reg_date, user_pref, user_last_login FROM Users WHERE (user_email='$e' AND user_pass=SHA1('$p')) AND user_active IS NULL";       
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made.

   // Register the values & redirect:
   $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   session_write_close();           
   mysqli_close($dbc);
   $url = BASE_URL . '/CustomIndex.php'; // Define the URL:
   ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
   header("Location: $url");
   exit(); // Quit the script.
}
?>
```

FILE 2: CustomIndex.php

```
<?
ob_start();
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user_first_name'])) {
   if(isset($_GET['custom2'])){
      $url = BASE_URL . '/index.php'; // Define the URL.
      ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
      header("Location: $url");
      exit(); // Quit the script.
   }
   sleep(5);
   $url = BASE_URL . "/CustomIndex.php?custom2=1";
   ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
   header("Location: $url");
   exit(); // Quit the script.
}

if(isset($_SESSION['user_first_name'])){
//  …program code…
}
?>
```

When  FILE 1 (login.php) is executed, then maybe 10% of the time the "if (empty($_SESSION['user_first_name']))" statement in FILE 2 (CustomIndesx.php) is true, and instead of being executed, the client is redirected to index.php, as if the $_SESSION variables had not been set.

However, after that happens, if I run FILE 2 (CustomIndesx.php) directly, it reads the $_SESSION data and executes properly.

I added all that code after "SLEEP" to simulate running CustomIndesx.php manually, but except for delaying the redirect by 5 second, nothing changed.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this random behavior, and how to eliminate it?

Comment: BTW, these scripts are running on iPage.com

Comment: can you share your ``phpinfo()``'s session section.

Comment: [link to php session info](http://douglasgstinson.com/phpsessioninfo.rtf)

Comment: Some people says ``session.auto_start`` should be on. you can use for this ``ini_set`` function if you can't change the php.ini file. Other thing is little complicated, you can change session save handler files to redis. It'll be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1) An important thing is: `session_start()` must be the first code line in both pages. If not, the session is closed after finished running each page script.

See what happened in

- [PHP _Session variable no longer persistate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014255/php-session-variable-no-longer-persistate/44014343#44014343)
- [PHP session for tracking unique page views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987104/php-session-for-tracking-unique-page-views/43988807#43988807)

2) Then, in `login.php` code part:

```
session_write_close();           
mysqli_close($dbc);
$url = BASE_URL . '/CustomIndex.php'; // Define the URL:
ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url");
```

You are writing in session with `session_write_close()` and closing it. Then, in the CustomIndex.php you are trying to open it again. It seems that it's not the same session id opened. So, try to delete `session_write_close();` line and test again.

Good luck!

### EDIT 1:

**Login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$q = "SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_priv, user_reg_date, user_pref, user_last_login FROM Users WHERE (user_email='$e' AND user_pass=SHA1('$p')) AND user_active IS NULL";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    $url = BASE_URL . '/CustomIndex.php';
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**CustomIndex.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_first_name']) || empty($_SESSION['user_first_name'])) {
    echo 'SESSION USER_FIRST_NAME IS NOT SET!';
} else {
    echo 'SESSION USER_FIRST_NAME IS OK: ' . $_SESSION['user_first_name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I added "session_write_close()" in an attempt to solve the problem. So I have the same probnlwm with and without that code.

Comment: @DougStinson Did you put session_start() as first line?

Comment: @DougStinson Try again with the simplified answer of me. No `ob_...` functions needed and no redirects in `CustomIndex.php`, because you really need to narrow the "error"-prone causes.

Comment: I switched the order of ob_start() and session_start(). That may have helped, but since the problem is intermittent, only more testing will show for sure. Thanks

Comment: @DougStinson You are welcome. Test my EDIT 1 version and give feedback.