# Login Butto returning to the same page. Instead of Home

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

Iam creating a page. The sign up works fine and takes me to home page but after logging out and trying to login again. The login button redirects me back to the registration page.
Please Help! I have checked through over and over and cant find any error.
**login.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{error_reporting(1);
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','uni-saga');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];

    $que1=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from users where Email='$user' and Password='$pass'");
    $count1=mysqli_num_rows($que1);

    if($count1>0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['tempsagauser']=$user;
        $que6=mysqli_query("select * from users where Email='$user'");
        $rec6=mysqli_fetch_array($que6);
        $userid=$rec6[0];

        $que2=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from user_profile_pic where user_id=$userid");
        $count2=mysqli_num_rows($que2);

        if($count2>0)
        {
            $que3=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from user_secret_quotes where user_id=$userid");
            $count3=mysqli_num_rows($que3);
            if($count3>0)
            {
                $que4=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from user_secret_quotes where user_id=$userid");

                while($rec=mysqli_fetch_array($que4))
                {
                    $que2=$rec[3];
                    $ans2=$rec[4];
                }
                if($que2=="" && $ans2=="")
                {
                    header("location:saga_files/saga_step/saga_step3/Secret_Question2.php");
                }
                else
                {

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['sagauser']=$user;
                    $query1=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from users where Email=$user");
                    $rec1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
                    $userid=$rec1[0];
                    mysqli_query($connection,"update user_status set status='Online' where user_id='$userid'");
                    header("location:saga_files/saga_home/Home.php");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                header("location:saga_files/saga_step/saga_step2/Secret_Question1.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while($rec=mysqli_fetch_array($que1))
            {
                $Gender=$rec[4];
            }
            if($Gender=="Male")
            {
                header("location:saga_files/saga_step/saga_step1/Step1_Male.php");
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:saga_files/saga_step/saga_step1/Step1_Female.php");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $que5=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from users where Email='$user'");
        $count5=mysqli_num_rows($que5);

        if($count5>0)
        {
            header("location:Invalid_Password.php");
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:Invalid_Username.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include("Login.php");
    include("saga_files/saga_index_file/saga_SignUp_file/SignUp.php");
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>UniSaga</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <!--Google Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/fav.png"/>
    </head>
    <script>
    function time_get()
    {
        d = new Date();
        mon = d.getMonth()+1;
        time = d.getDate()+"-"+mon+"-"+d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes();
            }
</script>
<header id="header-inverse">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu">
        <div class="container">

          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index-register.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
          </div>

          </div>
          </nav>
          </header>
          <div id="lp-register">
        <div class="container wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="intro-texts">
                <h1 class="text-white">UniSaga</h1>
                <p>Connect With Students from other Your University and Other Universities and get the latest news on what is Happening Around these learning Institutions. <br /> <br />What Are You Waiting For. Join Now And Experience It Like Never Before.</p>
             </div>
          </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="reg-form-container">
            <div class="reg-options">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#register" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                </ul><!--Tabs End-->
              </div>

              <!--Registration Form Contents-->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="register">
                  <h3>Register Now !!!</h3>
                  <p class="text-muted">Its Free and Always Will Be.</p>

                  <!--Register Form-->
                  <form  method="post" name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="first_name" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                        <input id="first_name" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="first_name" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="last_name" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="last_name" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="last_name" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="email" title="Enter Email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="remail" class="sr-only">Re-Enter Email</label>
                        <input id="remail" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="remail" title="Enter Email" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Email"/>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <p class="birth"><strong>Date of Birth</strong></p>
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <label for="month" class="sr-only"></label>
                        <select name="day" class="form-control" id="Day">
                          <option value="Day" disabled selected>Day</option>
                         <script type="text/javascript">

        for(i=1;i<=31;i++)
        {
            document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>" + i + "</option>");
        }

    </script>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <label for="month" class="sr-only"></label>
                        <select name="month" class="form-control" id="Month">
                          <option value="Month" disabled selected>Month</option>
                            <script type="text/javascript">

        var m=new Array("","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
        for(i=1;i<=m.length-1;i++)
        {
            document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>" + m[i] + "</option>");
        }   
    </script>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <label for="year" class="sr-only"></label>
                        <select name="year" class="form-control" id="Year">
                          <option value="Year" disabled selected>Year</option>
                          <script type="text/javascript">

        for(i=2000;i>=1960;i--)
        {
            document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>" + i + "</option>");
        }

    </script>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="form-group gender">
                      <select name="sex" style="width:120;height:35;font-size:18px;padding:3;">
            <option value="Select Sex:"> Select Sex: </option>
            <option value="Female"> Female </option>
            <option value="Male"> Male </option>
        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="campus" class="sr-only">Campus</label>
                        <input id="campus" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="campus" title="Enter campus" placeholder="Your campus"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                      <label for="county" class="sr-only"></label>
                        <select name="county" class="form-control" id="county">
                          <option value="county" disabled selected>County</option>
                          <option value="Baringo">Baringo</option>
                          <option value="Bomet">Bomet</option>
                          <option value="Bungoma">Bungoma</option>
                          <option value="Busia">Busia</option>
                          <option value="Elgeyo">Elgeyo Marakwet</option>
                          <option value="Embu">Embu</option>
                          <option value="Garissa">Garissa</option>
                          <option value="Homa">Homa Bay</option>
                          <option value="Isiolo">Isiolo</option>
                          <option value="Kajiado">Kajiado</option>
                          <option value="Kakamega">Kakamega</option>
                          <option value="Kericho">Kericho</option>
                          <option value="Kiambu">Kiambu</option>
                          <option value="Kilifi">Kilifi</option>
                          <option value="Kirinyaga">Kirinyaga</option>
                          <option value="Kisii">Kisii</option>
                          <option value="Kisumu">Kisumu</option>
                          <option value="Kitui">Kitui</option>
                          <option value="Kwale">Kwale</option>
                          <option value="Laikipia">Laikipia</option>
                          <option value="Lamu">Lamu</option>
                          <option value="Machakos">Machakos</option>
                          <option value="Makueni">Makueni</option>
                          <option value="Mandera">Mandera</option>
                          <option value="Meru">Meru</option>
                          <option value="Migori">Migori</option>
                          <option value="Marsabit">Marsabit</option>
                          <option value="Mombasa">Mombasa</option>
                          <option value="Muranga">Muranga</option>
                          <option value="Nairobi">Nairobi</option>
                          <option value="Nakuru">Nakuru</option>
                          <option value="Nandi">Nandi</option>
                          <option value="Narok">Narok</option>
                          <option value="Nyamira">Nyamira</option>
                          <option value="Nyandarua">Nyandarua</option>
                          <option value="Nyeri">Nyeri</option>
                          <option value="Samburu">Samburu</option>
                          <option value="Siaya">Siaya</option>
                          <option value="Taita">Taita Taveta</option>
                          <option value="Tana">Tana River</option>
                          <option value="Tharaka">Tharaka Nithi</option>
                          <option value="Trans">Trans Zoia</option>
                          <option value="Turkana">Turkana</option>
                          <option value="Uasin">Uasin Gishu</option>
                          <option value="Vihiga">Vihiga</option>
                          <option value="Wajir">Wajir</option>
                          <option value="West">West Pokot</option>
                            </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="signup" id="sign_button" class="btn btn-primary" / onClick="time_get()" >Register Now</button>
                  </form>

                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="login">
                  <h3>Login</h3>
                  <p class="text-muted">Log into your account</p>

                  <!--Login Form-->
                  <form method="post" name="Login_form" id='Login_form'>
                     <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="my-email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input id="my-email" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="username" title="Enter Email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label for="my-password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input id="my-password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="Forgot_Password.php">Forgot Password</a></p>
                  <button name="Login" id="login_button" class="btn btn-primary">Login Now</button>
                  </form><!--Login Form Ends--> 

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">

            <!--Social Icons-->
            <ul class="list-inline social-icons">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-googleplus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-pinterest"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--preloader-->
    <div id="spinner-wrapper">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts
    ================================================= -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.incremental-counter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
<?php
    include("saga_files/saga_index_file/saga_erorr_file/saga_erorr.php");
?>                  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this. You are also storing passwords in plaintext, you need to change this.

Comment: Is that the reason it keeps redirecting me to the same page?

Comment: No, but its the reason literally anyone could delete your entire database in one simple click.

Comment: How do i solve that?

Comment: Google. Read. Learn. You may want to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Please make a clearer text here: "_The sign up works fine and takes me to home page but after logging out and trying to login again. The login button ..._"

Answer (score 0):

1) Your session doesn't preserve its state, e.g. it's closed immediately after your `login.php` page finished processing. That happens because you're calling `session_start()` inside your code in `login.php`. So, you must move your `session_start()` to the first line in `login.php`. No code should reside before it.
And use it ONLY ONCE! (You use `session_start` twice)

See: [PHP session for tracking unique page views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987104/php-session-for-tracking-unique-page-views/43988807#43988807)

2) Also: `Login_form` needs an `action` attribute (`login.php`). Otherwise the form is posted to the page were it resides, e.g to `index.php`. So:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" name="Login_form" id="Login_form">
```

3) And there is a typo here (/):

```
<button type="submit" name="signup" id="sign_button" class="btn btn-primary" / onClick="time_get()" >Register Now</button>
```

Good luck.