# Session disappear after page refresh

Tags: php, session

This is the first time that I'm using sessions on PHP.
Getting some info from StackOverflow and other websites I'm into to build my first PHP Login but I'm getting a problem and don't know how to resolve it.

Basically at the moment that I set a session, after the page refresh, this session disappear. Is not supposed to remain for an amount of time? (that can be set with `set_cookie_params` etc, but this is another topic)

I have at the beginning of my page (global) this code:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);

session_name("RANDOMID");
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['ipremote'] !== getUserIP() && $_SESSION['useragent'] !== getUserAgent())
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
else
{
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    $_SESSION['ipremote'] = getUserIP();
    $_SESSION['useragent'] = getUserAgent();
}
```

then in my **login.php** file, when the user insert the right infos:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = 3;

header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

The problem that after the redirect the uid session disappear: I put at the end of the **index.php** page a `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION` variable, and I see just the IP and user-agent that is set everytime in the `else` condition.

**EDIT**: I tried to replace all the content of the session initialization with just `session_start();` and it works, I don't understand why this secure session initialization it doesn't working and making the session disappear.

Comment: on `index.php` also `session_start();`  required on top, in case you want to access SESSION variables and values

Comment: It's already setted, because the first portion of code is global (is required on both files, login.php and index.php) at the beginning.

Comment: `session_name("RANDOMID")` – Is that literally "RANDOMID", or does this mean you're randomly generating a new id every time here…?

Comment: It's just a random name, so it's literally RANDOMID (no defines or variables)

Comment: You use `session_regenerate_id(true)` when you have just destroyed the session.

Comment: if you still have the issue try adding session_start(); on top of login.php file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you calling your page via `https://` when you are testing this ...?

Otherwise, the explanation is simple:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

This makes PHP set the session cookie with the `secure` flag, meaning the browser is only allowed to send this cookie back with requests made over a secure connection.

So if you are actually testing this via HTTP only, then the session cookie will not be send back with the next request, so PHP does not find any session id, and therefor starts a fresh, new session when you call session_start ...

Answer (score 0):

that *RANDOMID* may change when you refresh/change your page depending on how you generate it!
so make sure you **use the same 'session_name'** in all youre pages before starting the session, like this.

login page

```
session_name("SAME_NAME");
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid'] = 3;
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

index page

```
session_name("SAME_NAME");
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['uid']);
exit;
```

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that the name is randomly generated, but OP explains in the comments on his post that he in fact does not randomly generate the session name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, slightly altered snippet below, to replace your `global` code being in the beginning of every page.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);

// start session
session_start();
// if session just started and uid is not set, add initial information such as user agent and ip address
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    $_SESSION['ipremote'] = getUserIP();
    $_SESSION['useragent'] = getUserAgent();
}
else
{
    // uid is set in session variables. User gets logged out in case of changed ip address and user agent.  
    if ($_SESSION['ipremote'] !== getUserIP() && $_SESSION['useragent'] !== getUserAgent())
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();            
    }
    // if client information has not changed just regenerate the session
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check **session.save_path**

1. find session.save_path from **phpinfo()**
2. check if it exists or not. if not, make it with **mkdir**.
3. check its permission. change it to others can read/write(**chmod 707**)

when I installed new php extension(SOAPClient) via yum on my dev server(AWS EC2 Linux AMI), experienced session disappearing when refresh or page move like you.

The reason was my session directory's permission changed to 500, even though i didn't anything. so php couldn't write session file to disk.

hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `session_start()` must be the first line of your code.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987104/php-session-for-tracking-unique-page-views/43988807#43988807) in an old answer of mine too.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please use session_start() on top of each page, it is required to access the session data on the page.